# Who did Naruto summon?

Tags: naruto

On the last page of Naruto chapter 633 Naruto, Sasuke and Sakura use summoning techniques.
Who is the big frog that Naruto summoned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **UPDATE!** This was confirmed in chapter 634.

Actually, based on the patterns on his body and face, I'd say that it's actually Gamakichi.

It's consistent with what this **[page on NarutoWiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Gamakichi)** says, although I don't know how reliable a source that is.

Comment: At first I thought it was Gamabunta. But based on the patterns on his body and face i think it is more Gamakichi.

Answer (score 5):

Naruto summoned [Gamakichi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Gamakichi).
[image: Gamakichi]

Sasuke summoned [Aoda](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Aoda).
[image: Aoda]

Sakura summoned [Katsuyu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Katsuyu).
[image: Katsuyu]

Answer (score 5):

It is Gamakichi, as Naruto himself confirmed. In turn, Gamakichi said that his dad (Gamabunta) was busy.